# How can my villain be resurrected as a construct?

Tags: dnd-5e, constructs, resurrection

I’m running a 5e campaign in a Homebrew setting. My BBEG is a rather powerful being kind of... locked in a fixed, repeating point in time. I've taken quite a few liberties here, but in order to continue to influence the world around him, he has been taking "avatars", in a sense—essentially, he slaps a splinter of his consciousness/mind/soul/essence/whatever on top of the (willing) vessel's own consciousness, resulting in rather, uh... mentally unstable enemies. Now to the actual question at hand.

One of these avatars was killed by my ever-so-illustrious party, and a particularly angry PC curb stomped her poor little head in. However, the party did nothing with or to the body to ensure she would stay dead. I, capable of limitless cruelty when the mood strikes me, have decided I want to resurrect her—but ideally, as a construct. I'm sure there's some other way around the head-smashy bit, but I want her to be ***angry***.

So, what I want to know is, can I do this, and if so, how? Everything I could find on Warforged seemed to imply that I couldn't drop an already existing soul into one, let alone golems.

**How can a soul be resurrected or transferred into a construct body?**

Comment: Note that we don't allow "idea generation" questions here (those are [more suited to a forum](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5449/ive-been-told-my-question-is-better-suited-to-a-forum-but-where-should-i-go). However, the question otherwise seems fine, so I've edited that part out of your question.

Comment: Obligatory OOTS entry begins here: http://www.giantitp.com/comics/oots0971.html

Comment: @cpcodes Please don’t “provide ideas” in comments. [Those are answers and don’t belong in the comments.](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6533/321)

Answer (score 5):

## *Raise Dead*, *Magic Jar*, Possess a Warforged

*Raise dead* that didn't restore missing parts, so BBEG procured a scroll of *magic jar* or other method for casting it.

[*Raise dead*](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Raise%20Dead#content):

> This spell closes all mortal wounds, but it doesn't restore missing body parts. If the creature is lacking body parts or organs integral for its [s]urvival - its head, for instance - the spell automatically fails.

[*Magic Jar*](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Magic%20Jar#h-Magic%20Jar):

> You can attempt to possess any humanoid within 100 feet of you that you can see (creatures warded by a [Protection from Evil and Good](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Protection%20from%20Evil%20and%20Good#h-Protection%20from%20Evil%20and%20Good) or [Magic Circle](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Magic%20Circle#h-Magic%20Circle) ⁠spells can't be possessed).

### Plot Mechanism

As a plot mechanism, the BBEG could possess the warforged he hired or convinced to help him while he was weak.  That can add a complication as the PCs might not want to destroy the body of an innocent or coerced warforged.

Answer (score -1):

The obvious one is to have her raised as any of a variety of kinds of undead (depending on the party CR).  A Revenant would be particularly appropriate, as they're all about being enraged over how they got murdered.

Other than that, it might be a bit of a stretch, but a flesh golem could work.  Traditionally, Flesh Golems don't remember anything from their previous lives and require more than one corpse, but you can handwave those pretty easily if you have a mind to.

Really, though, you're already in a homebrew setting.  Decide on a monster you want to use, declare something that sounds halfway plausible for how she got there, and say that it works.  In 5e in particular, you as the DM don't need to limit yourself to what the book says about how you can do things.

Comment: What mechanic can they use to turn it into a flesh golem? Also, Undead aren't constructs.

Comment: Thanks for the thoughts, the flesh golem is an idea I might utilize after my party has killed a few more of his little flesh Ferraris, but as NautArch said, undead isn't where I want to go with this. It's important that she retains full will. But, you're right, it is already home brew. Caution to the wind.